# Get link in a <span>

Tags: html-agility-pack

I get for "span a text" this code but i want get link href (not the link text).
Help me please.

```
   Dim html As String = "<span class=myclass><a href=abc.html>text text a text</a></span>"
   Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
   doc.LoadHtml(html)
   Dim titles As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='myclass']")
   For Each title In titles
      MsgBox(title.InnerText)
   Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to get the value of the _attribute:

```
title.Attributes("href").Value
```